# R - specify columns in grid.table to be bold

Tags: r, gridextra, r-grid

I've got a table with 3 columns and I'm using grid.table to generate a pdf version. I want two of those columns to be in bold and keep the other one as plain text. I've not found a general solution to this, the grid.table cran page only shows you how to edit fontface for rows or specific cells.

Using a small sample dataset (due to sensitivity):

```
> dput(Data)
structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
Subloc = structure(1:6, .Label = c("A1","A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "C1"), 
class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(3L,3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), 
.Label = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Meta"), 
class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

My existing code:

```
    maxrow <- c(30);
    npages <- ceiling(nrow(Data)/maxrow);
    pdf(paste0("DATE.pdf"), height = 11, width = 10)
    idx <- seq(1, maxrow)
    grid.table(Data[idx, ], rows = NULL, theme = ttheme_minimal(core=list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0.1, fontface = c("bold"))),
                                                           rowhead=list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0)), colhead=list(fg_params=list(fontsize = 14, col="#660066", fontface="bold"))))
    for (i in 2:npages){
     grid.newpage();
    if(i*maxrow <= nrow(Data)) {
    idx <- seq(1+((i-1)*maxrow), i*maxrow)}  else{
       idx <- seq(1+((i-1)*maxrow), nrow(Data))}grid.table(Data[idx,], rows =NULL,theme = ttheme_minimal(core=list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0.1)), rowhead=list(fg_params=list(hjust=0, x=0)),colhead=list(fg_params=list(fontsize = 14, col="#660066", fontface="bold"))))
}dev.off()
```

I want to make the data inside the Location and Type columns (not the column headers) to be in bold. I've managed to make all the column contents bold in the fg_params=list wrapper, but don't know how to specify the columns I want this treatment for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
library(gridExtra)

tt <- ttheme_default()
tt$core$fg_params <- list(fontface=matrix(c(1,2,3), ncol=ncol(d),nrow=nrow(d),byrow=TRUE))

grid.table(d, theme=tt)
```

Code output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @user10697133 That is a cool first answer! Consider also that @Pryore would like to have the headers in plain font, so something like this `list(fg_params=list(fontface='plain'))` for `colhead` could be integrated in your answer.

Comment: @user10697133, thanks for your contribution. Just one thing though, how do I specify the fontface of either of those 3 columns. By itself, your code doesn't make my first and second column bold. Maybe I'm missing something, could you clarify please?

Comment: I've basically tried to assign fontface to the matrix indices after using the code you wrote for me, i.e. `tt$core$fg_params <- list(fontface = c("bold","plain","bold"))`, but this transforms the core text by row where each 1st and 3rd row of my data is bold rather than by column. Thanks for your help once again

Comment: @Pryore that's why you need a matrix (of the same size as your core content); a vector will get recycled row-wise.

Comment: It works with the sample data I've given, but having problems with my main dataset. What appears to be happening is while the matrix (using the index c(1,2,3) you suggested) is correctly generating, the actual aesthetic changes are not occuring. Instead all the core content defaults to plain-text. So I tried an alternative of c("bold","plain","bold") and everything in my table turns bold.

Comment: @user10697133 it appears to have something to do with idx variable and subsetting